# How to deserialize Newtonsoft Json.NET references to separate, individual instances

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a piece of JSON that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "Name": "James",
    "BirthDate": "1983-03-08T00:00Z",
    "LastModified": "2012-03-21T05:40Z"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "1"
  }
]
```

As you can tell by the $ref, this JSON array contains the same Person (James), twice. The second time is a reference to the first.

I am wondering if there is a way to **deserialize** this JSON into an object that contains two **copies** of the James person.

Currently, I'm using this:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
     PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
     ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};

var deserializedPersons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

But this just gives me an array with the same instance of the Person, twice:

```
object.ReferenceEquals(deserializedPersons[0], deserializedPersons[1]) // Evaluates to true
```

I've found a workaround I am unhappy with which is simply deserializing the JSON string, then serializing it using the jsonSerializerSettings above, which will duplicate the person in the JSON, then deserializing it *again*. This is causing major slowdowns for the large objects we are using.

**Note**: I know I could change the API that I retrieve this JSON from to duplicate the data, but preserving the references saves *substantial* space when sending the response JSON over the wire.

Comment: IF *slow down* is the REAL question, just use [JSONFAST](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON) its twice as fast as James Newton-Kings implementation.

Comment: Would it be suitable to iterate over your person list, and clone each person after deserialization?

Comment: Ah, I misread - I thought he was trying to get rid of the refs

Comment: @recursive No need to do that if you use a custom reference resolver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [custom reference resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IReferenceResolver.htm). For example, assuming `Name` is the "primary key" for your objects, this should work. Of course, you may want to make it more generic.

```
public class PersonReferenceResolver : IReferenceResolver
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, Person> _objects = 
        new Dictionary<string, Person>();

    public object ResolveReference(object context, string reference)
    {
        Person p;
        if (_objects.TryGetValue(reference, out p))
        {
            //This is the "clever" bit. Instead of returning the found object
            //we just return a copy of it.
            //May be better to clone your class here...
            return new Person
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                BirthDate = p.BirthDate,
                LastModified = p.LastModified
            };
        }

        return null;
    }

    public string GetReference(object context, object value)
    {
        Person p = (Person)value;
        _objects[p.Name] = p;

        return p.Name;
    }

    public bool IsReferenced(object context, object value)
    {
        Person p = (Person)value;

        return _objects.ContainsKey(p.Name);
    }

    public void AddReference(object context, string reference, object value)
    {
        _objects[reference] = (Person)value;
    }
}
```

Now you deserialise like this:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ReferenceResolver = new PersonReferenceResolver()
};

var deserializedPersons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(
    json, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

---

**Edit:** I was bored so I made a generic version:

```
public class GenericResolver<TEntity> : IReferenceResolver
    where TEntity : ICloneable, new()
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, TEntity> _objects = new Dictionary<string, TEntity>();
    private readonly Func<TEntity, string> _keyReader;

    public GenericResolver(Func<TEntity, string> keyReader)
    {
        _keyReader = keyReader;
    }

    public object ResolveReference(object context, string reference)
    {
        TEntity o;
        if (_objects.TryGetValue(reference, out o))
        {
            return o.Clone();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public string GetReference(object context, object value)
    {
        var o = (TEntity)value;
        var key = _keyReader(o);
        _objects[key] = o;

        return key;
    }

    public bool IsReferenced(object context, object value)
    {
        var o = (TEntity)value;
        return _objects.ContainsKey(_keyReader(o));
    }

    public void AddReference(object context, string reference, object value)
    {
        if(value is TEntity)
            _objects[reference] = (TEntity)value;
    }
}
```

With slightly new usage:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    //Now we need to specify the type and how to get the object's key
    ReferenceResolver = new GenericResolver<Person>(p => p.Name)
};

var deserializedPersons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(
    json, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Comment: I'm on mobile right now but I'll evaluate this tonight! Seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with $ref deserialization.
PreserveReferencesHandling helps only if you have metadata located at the beginning of the request/response.
Otherwise I recommend using those:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects; 
settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore; //ign
var deserializedObjects = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(requestResult.Content, settings);
```

Regarding to https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MetadataPropertyHandling.htm

```
Default 0   Read metadata properties located at the start of a JSON object.
ReadAhead   1   Read metadata properties located anywhere in a JSON object. Note that this setting will impact performance.
Ignore  2   Do not try to read metadata properties.
```