# json references are not preserved when deserializing data

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to load json data into my database. The data is highly structured, and has the potential for numerous elements to be repeated throughout the structure. For repeated elements, I would like to use id's and references so I don't need to duplicate code.

I am currently using json.NET for the deserialization, and I can not get references to deserialize properly. I keep winding up with null values for the elements I try to populate with references.

I have tried structuring the references a myriad of ways, both using id's and using URI syntax. I have gotten the same result no matter how I structure the references.

Here's the c# code I am using for deserialization:

```
String dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot\\json\\";
String incidentJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(dir + "incident_test.json");
IncidentArray incidents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IncidentArray>(
    incidentJson
    ,new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All }
);
```

Here's the class I am trying to deserialize the data to:

```
public class IncidentArray
{
    public Incident[] Incidents { get; set; }
}

public class Incident
{
    public Jurisdiction Jurisdiction { get; set; }
}

public class Jurisdiction
{
    public String Code { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here's an incident_test.json that parses just fine:

```
{
  "incidents": [
    {
        "jurisdiction": {
          "code": "CD",
          "name": "City Division",
          "description": "City Division, Portland OR USA"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's an incident_test.json with references. The jurisdiction comes out null in the deserialized object:

```
{
  "incidents": [
    {
      "jurisdiction": { "$ref": "1" }
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "jurisdiction": {
      "$id": "1",
      "code": "CD",
      "name": "City Division",
      "description": "City Division, Portland OR USA"
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect the object resulting from the deserialization to populate with the data in the referenced json data. As previously stated, I'm getting null instead.

**RESOLVED**: desmondgc definitely pointed me in the right direction with his answer below, but there's a little more to it than object order. I did some more testing considering object order and placement. This deserializes and captures the reference:

```
{
    "incidents": [
    {
      "jurisdiction": {
              "$id": "1",
          "code": "CD",
          "name": "City Division",
          "description": "City Division, Portland OR USA"
      }
    },
    {
      "jurisdiction": { "$ref": "1" }
    }
    ]
}
```

and if I construct the deserializer like this:

```
IncidentArray incidents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IncidentArray(
    incidentJson
    ,new JsonSerializerSettings {
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
        ,MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
    }
);
```

This works too:

```
{
    "incidents": [
    {
      "jurisdiction": {
          "code": "CD",
          "name": "City Division",
              "$id": "1",
          "description": "City Division, Portland OR USA"
      }
    },
    {
      "jurisdiction": { "$ref": "1" }
    }
    ]
}
```

due to the MetadataPropertyHandling property.

Obviously, order matters here, and in my original test data the order was wrong. Another important factor, however, seems to be the fact that in my initial test json, the object with the reference id was not actually being deserialized because it did not match the structure of the object I was deserializing to. As a result, there was no object to copy into the reference object when the deserializer was trying to process it.

So order matters, but object structure matters as well. The id property has to mark an object that the deserializer will process, and the reference object has to be in a place in the object graph where the deserializer recognizes it as the same type as the original object.

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964774/how-to-deserialize-newtonsoft-json-net-references-to-separate-individual-instan

Comment: I think the issue is that the reference `$ref` comes before the `$id` in the JSON.  The JSON is parsed in one pass so the `$id` has to come first in order to be able to resolve the reference.  If you have control over the JSON, try reversing the order of `definitions` and `incidents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably an issue due to appearance of $ref before $id, as described in the Json.NET docs:

> Metadata properties like $id must be located at the beginning of a JSON object to be successfully detected during deserialization. If you can't control the order of properties in your JSON object then MetadataPropertyHandling can be used to remove this restriction.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm