# Preserve $id & $values from API call in core 5.0

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-5.0

I'm developing in the new core 5.0.

I have the following static method for calling APIs:

```
public static async Task<T> CallApiAsync<T>(string url, object body, HttpMethod method, string accessToken = null, string accessTokenType = null)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        string responseContent = null;
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            
            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
            AddHeader(accessTokenType, accessToken, httpClient, httpRequestMessage);
            result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
              
            responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            };
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent, settings);
        }
    }
```

yet my responses comes in the form of:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "bills": {
        "$id": "2",
        "$values": [
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "id": "FEw3Gcw38GVB",
                "organizationId": "1"
            },
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "id": "D16FbgYcXr35",
                "organizationId": "2"
            }
          ]
       }
       }
```

My class is like this:

```
public class BillsRoot    {
  
      [JsonProperty]
      public List<Bill> bills { get; set; } 
}


public class Bill    {
    [JsonProperty]
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public string organizationId { get; set; } 
}
```

How do I prevent the $id & $values?

Comment: Prevent of what? What result did you expect to receive?

Comment: I don't have anything called a $values array in my objects, why is it there? Can't I remove it? I've also not added the $id properties, they're not a part of my objects either

Comment: And I expected these results but I didn't expect $ids to be added neither did I expect my bills to be in a $values array. Just the bills array alone

Comment: Do you want to get the value of each id ?

Comment: @fiverbox.com what do you mean? I just don't want these $id&$values to be added to my objects, they're not self-created.

Comment: new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.none}); did you try without this?

Comment: @TiagoSilva Yes, I actually didn't have the settings part as part of my program till my frontend-developer today asked me to prevent these. So that returns the same

Comment: await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage); is this line calling another api inside your application? The result actually is coming from this, make sure it is not coming with $id and $value already

Comment: @TiagoSilva It's calling an external API but this response does not have $id and $values included when calling it on Postman. It's a very clean response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964774/how-to-deserialize-newtonsoft-json-net-references-to-separate-individual-instan. See if this can help you.

Comment: Your JSON has `"$id": "3"` appear **twice**.  Does that happen in your real JSON, or is that something that was introduced while editing?

Comment: @eeee Try to set a breakpoint to check the value of the `responseContent`, whether it contains the '$id' and '$values' or not? If possible can you post the responsecontent? If the 'responseContent' contains the "$id" and "$values", perhaps the issue is related to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to explicit the name in attribute?

```
[JsonProperty("$id")]
```